# Showing that $\gcd(n,a_3)\rightarrow(n)\cap(a_3)$ using ideals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that

$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2),a_3).$$

My attempt is the following, let $(a_i)$ be the collection of ideals, for each the basis is $a_i$. Then

$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,a_3)\rightarrow(a_1)\cap(a_2)\cap(a_3) \equiv(m).$$

Now, let $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=n$ and

$$\gcd(n,a_3)\rightarrow(n)\cap(a_3).$$

But $(n)=(a_1)\cap(a_2)$, therefore

$$\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2),a_3)\rightarrow (a_1)\cap(a_2)\cap(a_3)$$

so

$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2),a_3)$$

as stated.

Comment: Seems awfully sophisticated, all we want to show that $e$ divides all of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ iff $e$ divides both $\gcd(a_1,a_2)$ and $a_3$.

Comment: ...and it's the maximum divisor of both sets of numbers. I find intersections most intuitive as it's more visual than algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @Alyosha: Geometric intuition is good. But maximum divisor is not of importance, since if the sets of divisors are the same, the maximum is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks. I know it may sound too sophisticated, but I'm studying a book in which the first concept introduced is that of a ideal, so It was natural to keep it that way. In any case if I show that the ideals corresponding to both sets of numbers are the same (which I think I proved in my question, and I'm asking if that is correct) I can use that $(b)=(c) \iff b=\pm c$

Comment: Yes, the method you use can be written up so that it is a proof. The arrows are a problem, they are obviously not intended to be implications.

Comment: @André Nicolas Hi, I reviewed the book and missed completely the point.. sorry. The intersection is for the least common multiple. Given a set of numbers $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ the intersection $\cap_{i}(a_i)$ is also an ideal so exists a number $m$ such that $\cap_{i}(a_i)=(m)$ where $m$ is the least common multiple. For the greatest common divisor the set to consider is $I=\{c_1a_1+...c_na_n\}$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ d\mid ((a,b),c)\iff d\mid(a,b), c\iff d\mid a,b,c$

Therefore $\rm\:((a,b),c)\:$ and $\rm\:(a,b,c)\:$ have the same set $\rm\,D\,$ of common divisors $\rm\,d,\,$ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\rm\,(=\ max\ D).$

Comment: Hi Math Gems thank you, I think that the idea is the same as mine, but much more clearly stated.